# How to append additional text when making a POST request?

Tags: vuejs2

I got a Vue app with an input text field in a form where the user can type a new name for a `branch`. The user can also click a checkbox to designate whether a branch is `active` or `inactive`. Then, he submits the form via a submit button which then sends a POST (or PUT if he is editing the existing data) request to a remote data API.

**Demo screenshot:**

[image]

My question: **I need to append the text `(inactive)` to the branch name when it is submitted to the server if the `active` checkbox is not selected, but also need to remove that inactive text if it exists and the `active` checkbox is left unchecked:**

*Hypothetical branch name with inactive flag and checkbox not checked:*

```
ABCD (inactive)
```

*Hypothetical branch name if active checkbox checked:*

```
ABCD
```

Here is sample code for my POST method:

```
onSubmitAdd() {
  this.loading = true
  ApiService.postBranch(this.branch)
    .then(() => {
      this.loading = false
      this.$router.push({ path: '/branches' })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      if (err.response) {
        this.errors = err.response.data
      } else {
        if (err.request) {
          this.errors = err.request
        } else {
          this.errors = err.message
        }
      }
      this.loading = false
      console.error('Error from post', err)
    })
}
```

Thanks for any tips you can provide for the logic to make this happen!

Answer (score 0):

Add a **v-model** with your checkbox and based on that input you can decide whether to add or not the **inactive** text in your **onSubmitAdd** function

Answer (score 0):

The `conditional text` is not appended when sending the post request. You have already set the state to be active or inactive (and of course your Api is expecting to read a boolean value e.g `"branchStatus": boolean`).
You set the conditional when you are retrieving the information with a get request which will return JSON data that should contain the state. You can then set the display text based on the state.

```
let displayStatus = ''
response.branchStatus ? displayStatus = "active" : displayStatus = "inactive"
```